# Get the same shadow in all modern browsers (except IE version 9)

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css, cross-browser

I've been trying to get the same shadow in all modern browsers (except IE version 9).
Unfortunately, for example Google Chrome doesn't blur it as nice as Firefox does.

Here's my code..

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">Every browser should see my shadow the same way!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -4px #000, 4px 0 0 0 #E8EBEF;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E8EBEF;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hLp8J/1/

What can I do to get the same shadow in at least the latest versions of Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari and Opera? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Normally, I'd also be that type of guy who'd post a link like this ;-) But in this case it's important, because the shadow is going to be in combination with a picture placed next to it which continues the shadow.. and in chrome the blur/spread effect is not the same.

Comment: Basic problem: the browsers are using different rendering engines which (shockingly) render things differently. Trying to get browsers to render pages pixel perfect is always going to be a recipe for frustration. In your case, you would be best off redoing the graphic so that the continuation shadow is also rendered by the browser (that could be another box shadow, or done using SVG or canvas. This is more likely to get you a consistent look.

Comment: by the way -- you should probably also test in browsers on the mac and on mobile devices, because these will probably also render differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different rendering engines draw the shadow slightly differently (Firefox for example has a smoother falloff than Webkit based browsers, looks better if you ask me)

The only way to guarantee it'll look identical across browsers is to be dumb about it and use images.

Otherwise you need to find a way to deal with the minor differences without adversely affecting your design.

Answer (score 1):

You may try online **[CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)** or **[CSS3 Box Shadow Generator](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/)** or **[CSS3 Maker](http://www.css3maker.com/)**